# Replaced starter, alternator, fuse still won’t start

Tags: starting, dodge, charger

We have replaced the starter, alternator, and fuse and the car still won’t start. When we put the alternator in it started and ran twice. Now it wont, so we put another battery in it, still wont start.

Comment: What do you see and hear when you try to start it?  Is the starter turning?  Lights on dash?

Comment: Post the make, model, year, engine and transmission please.